# angularfire2 cant find module 'firebase/app'

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

app.component :

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { RoomComponent } from './component/room/room.component';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { FirebaseService } from "./service/firebase.service";
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';


imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseconfig),
  AngularFirestoreModule
],
providers: [
  FirebaseService,
  {
    provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG,
    useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG
  },
  AngularFireAuth
],
```

package.json file :

```
{
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.1",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"dateformat": "^3.0.3",
"firebase": "^5.5.1",
"rxjs": "^6.3.2",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
"ts-node": "~4.1.0",
"tslint": "~5.9.1",
"typescript": "~2.5.3"
}
}
```

The imports that doesnt work located in a service:

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, 
   AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

I only included the dependencies that may have something to do with the error but if i missed something please tell me.

I've already tried multiple versions. This does work but it has an error. The problem lies within the import { auth } which allows me to login to firebase. I dont know what the problem is. Sometimes it compiles, sometimes it doesn't. This is the only version combination I used so far that compile sometimes even with error. Other versions just breaks other imports.

The project only compiles if i remove the auth import momentarily and then put it back in then save it.

Comment: Why `AngularFireAuth` and `auth` from `firebase/app` both are used? `AngularFireAuth` would serve the purpose.

Comment: I followed this : https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md. I get errors when i remove the auth.

Comment: I also see that you've Angular 5, but with `rxjs 6` and `rxjs-compat`. `@angular/fire 5.0.1` is built for Angular 6 and with `rxjs 6`. If possible, please try with Angular 6, `@angular/fire 5.0.2` and remove `rxjs-compat` (to ensure only `rxjs 6` dependencies are used). I don't use `auth` from `firebase/app` at all, while using `@angular/fire 5.0.x`. Please share any particular error - after these changes.

Comment: It is always useful to check the `package.json` of `angularfire2` (use the tag of the particular release of angularfire2 being used) and check for correct version of `firebase` used and match the same in our angular app `package.json` - for better compatibility. Sometimes incompatible version of `firebase` with `angularfire2` causes issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gonna start with the big one, and I'd just say try deleting your `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` then re-run the command `npm install`. On top of that just a few suggestions...

#### app.component (app.module?)

Your imports and files are inconsistent, I see you importing from `angularfire2` as well as `@angular/fire`. And while they're effectively the same thing, it's just that the Angular team is migrating/migrated to `@angular/fire`. Run `npm uninstall angularfire2` then `npm i @angular/fire`. Finally you should update your `app.component` (I think you mean `app.module`) as so...

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { RoomComponent } from './component/room/room.component';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { FirebaseService } from "./service/firebase.service";
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';


imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseconfig),
  AngularFirestoreModule,
  AngularFireAuthModule // IMPORT THE AUTH MODULE IF YOU'RE GOING TO USE IT
],
  providers: [
    FirebaseService,
    {
      provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG,
      useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG
    },
    // AngularFireAuth (don't need/should not provide this, allow the module to set this up)
  ],
```

Mind you I'd love to be able to see more code, if you have a repo and would like for me to check that out I can provide additional help, but hopefully this'll be a solid start/fix.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it already and I did some of what you said. I updated those imports but it still didn't work . Fixed it by changing firebase/app into just firebase. I think it was changed in later versions and my import is old.

Answer (score 9):

```
npm install firebase
```

Solved my issue

Answer (score 5):

Install firebase using this command `npm i @angular/fire`

Answer (score 0):

In your app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: ""
};

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Make sure it's the app.module.ts not app.component.ts. What error are you getting?

Comment: src/app/service/firebase.service.ts(4,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'. It's working correctly, it just has this error I dont know why